# Combine rows/observations by column value in R

Tags: r, package

I have a data frame with three columns:

```
 ID        Class     Score
 abc123    Science   1
 jkl456    Math      0
 zpe789    English   1
 abc123    Science   0
 jkl456    Math      0
 yth293    Art       1
```

I want to combine observations by ID, and add a column that sums their scores (Total Score), shows the number they attempted (even if they got it wrong), and calculates the percent correct, like so:

```
 ID        Class     Total Score     Number Attempted      Percent
 abc123    Science   1               2                      50
 jkl456    Math      0               2                       0
 zpe789    English   1               1                     100
 yth293    Art       1               1                     100
```

Are there any R packages or functions that could collapse across ID and corresponding Class and produce these results?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df <- read.table(textConnection("ID        Class     Score
 abc123    Science   1
 jkl456    Math      0
 zpe789    English   1
 abc123    Science   0
 jkl456    Math      0
 yth293    Art       1"), header = TRUE)
```

Then do:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise("Total_Score" = sum(Score),
            "Number_Attempted" = n(),
            "Percent" = (Total_Score/Number_Attempted)*100)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize(TotalScore = sum(Score), 
            NumberAttempted=n(), 
            Percent = TotalScore/NumberAttempted*100)
#Source: local data frame [4 x 4]
#
#      ID TotalScore NumberAttempted Percent
#1 abc123          1               2      50
#2 jkl456          0               2       0
#3 yth293          1               1     100
#4 zpe789          1               1     100
```

To demonstrate how useful the `dplyr` package is, here is a similar solution using no special packages.

```
newdf <- data.frame(TotalScore = with(df, tapply(Score, ID, FUN=sum)))
newdf$NumberAttempted <- with(df, tapply(Score, ID, FUN=length))
newdf$Percent <- 100*newdf$TotalScore/newdf$NumberAttempted
newdf
#       TotalScore NumberAttempted Percent
#abc123          1               2      50
#jkl456          0               2       0
#yth293          1               1     100
#zpe789          1               1     100
```

As an ending note, variable names with spaces can create difficulties in further analysis.

Comment: Thank you!  Looks similar to the one provided above, so I'm sure it'll work.  I appreciate your help!

Comment: It is the same. We must have posted at the same time. I added a `base R` solution to show what the `dplyr` package is doing.